# Change font of label in collection view cell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a `CollectionViewController` as follows

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

  var dogs = ["Dog1", "Dog2","Dog3"]

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.testLabel.text = dogs[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

and `CustomCell` as follows

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
}
```

I like to change the font size as 18 above, but I am getting the font that I set in the storyboard manually. So is there a way that I can change font programatically in the `controller` or do I need to change it in `CustomCell`

P.S. Just found out this happens, when I set manually fonts on device sizes available and if I remove those manual device sizes it works. Is there anyway I can override this and have both at same time?

Comment: Replace cell.testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18) to cell.testLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: can you try this  @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
         testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
        }
    }

Comment: I tried that in CustomCell, like you told and it did not work.

Comment: Have you solved the issue or still facing the problem?

Comment: @Bapu, Just found out this happens, when I set manually fonts on device sizes available and if I remove those manual device sizes it works. Is there anyway I can override this and have both at same time?

Answer (score 2):

Directly change in "cellForItemAt" method as

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.testLabel.text = ["Dog1", "Dog2", "Dog3"]

    cell.testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this was my problem.
and its solution very simple
All we have to do is first specify font with correct font string name then add string 
i.e `cell.testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
cell.testLabel.text = dogs[indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 1):

use this code it will help you

```
label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(20) //20 is font size
```

Swift 3:

```
label.font = label.font.withSize(20)
```

or try

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
```

Comment: Where do you put that?

Comment: in "cellForItemAtIndexPath" delegate method

Comment: That doesnt help

Comment: try UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)

Comment: That did not work and also I dont want to use system font.

Answer (score 1):

use **awakeFromNib** method, from apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib),

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each
>   object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in
>   the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an object receives
>   an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and
>   action connections already established.

you can change the label font in this method.

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing font name to "HelveticaNeue-Bold" and see if it works

Comment: Just found out this happens, when I set manually fonts on device sizes available and if I remove those manual device sizes it works. Is there anyway I can override this and have both at same time?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change **cellForItemAt** to be this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

      cell.testLabel.text = "Dog 1"
      cell.testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)

      return cell
}
```

Then please check the following:

1. Your reuse identifier is setup correctly in the storyboard.
2. Your collectionView delegate is set.
3. Your collectionView datasource is set.
4. The outlet for the label is connected.
5. You reload the collectionView data
6. Check the font name is correct, you can use FontBook on the mac to check spelling.

Comment: Where do you reload the collectionView data?

Comment: How are you getting the data you want to show in the collectionView?

Comment: From that array of dogs

Comment: Make sure you use cell.testLabel.text = "Dog 1", not an array of strings too.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect what you said, but still it doesnt work

Comment: Ok can you show the rest of the UICollectionView delegates & data source functions such as func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157979/discussion-between-coder221-and-neil-faulkner).

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't understand why have you written `func viewDidLayoutSubviews()` inside `cellForItemAt` `delegate` method. Just remove it from there.

Secondly, you don't need to call `collectionView.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad()` since it will automatically load the `collectionView` first time with the data you provided.

Before proceeding to changing the font, check if your required font **(HelveticaNeue)** is available in the system. If not first install the font and add it to your project.

Now coming to changing the `font` of the `label`. It can be done in 2 ways:

**1.** Use `awakeFromNib()` in your `CustomCell`, i.e.

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
    }
}
```

This will set the cell's font **only once when the cell is loaded from the nib**. It is **recommended** if there are no further changes in the `label's font` after configuring it once.

**2.** Configure the font in `cellForItemAt`, i.e.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.testLabel.text = dogs[indexPath.row]
    cell.testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
    return cell
}
```

This will set the cell's font **each time `cellForItemAt delegate` method is called**, i.e. every-time the cell is reloaded. Use this if you want to make any conditional changes in the cells when reloading.

Comment: Just found out this happens, when I set manually fonts on device sizes available and if I remove those manual device sizes it works. Is there anyway I can override this and have both at same time?

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve.